# ASP.NET MVC - jQuery Sortable

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a list of menu items which can be sorted. I have the sort working which is based on this [link](http://blog.codeville.net/2009/01/01/drag-and-drop-sorting-for-our-aspnet-mvc-list-editor-in-one-line-of-code/).

However, I'm not sure how to save the order of the menu items to the database? I'm using nhibernate.

View Code

```
<h3>Sort Main Menus</h3>
<% using(Html.BeginForm()) { %>
    <p>You can drag the items into a different order</p>
    <p></p>
    <div id="items">
        <% foreach (var mainMenusList in ViewData.Model) 
           {%>
             <%Html.RenderPartial("MainMenuEditor", mainMenusList, new ViewDataDictionary(ViewData) { { "mainMenuName", "mainMenu" } });%>     
           <%} 
        %>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Save changes" />
 <% } %>

 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() 
    {
        $("#items").sortable({ axis: "y" });
    });
</script>
```

MainMenuEditor Code

```
<div>
 <input type="hidden" name="<%= ViewData["mainMenuName"] + ".index" %>" value="<%= ViewData.Model.Id %>" />
 <% var fieldPrefix = string.Format("{0}[{1}].", ViewData["mainMenuName"], ViewData.Model.Id); %>
 <%= Html.Hidden(fieldPrefix + "MainMenuID", ViewData.Model.Id) %>
 <%= Html.TextBox(fieldPrefix + "Name", ViewData.Model.MainMenuName, new { size = "30"})%></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need a `<form>`-tag, and submit that form you your controller. The controller needs to pass the data to the model, and the model will make that the data is saved in the database.